# Upgrading openSUSE 11.1 with Plesk Panel 9.3 to PHP 5.3

Tags: php, opensuse

I'm running a VPS with openSUSE 11.1 (i586). On the VPS is Parallels Plesk Panel 9.3.0 installed. The current PHP-version is PHP 5.2.11. I want to upgrade PHP to PHP 5.3, but I can't find good instructions on how to do this.

If I check for updates in Zypper, it says this is the latest release. In the Plesk Updates isn't an update either, both via the webbased interface and the command line interface.

On Software.openSUSE.org I can find packages for PHP 5.3.1 in both the 
[server:php/server_apache_openSUSE_11.1](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:/php/server_apache_openSUSE_11.1)-repo and the server:php/openSUSE_11.1-repo (can't post the link because I'm a newbie here). But if I add one of those to Zypper, I still don't see an update.

Is there here somebody who knows how to do this? And is it completely safe to update that way? I don't want to end up with a broken VPS...

Thanks! Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to recompile PHP to get 5.3 on there. Unless Plesk has any difficulties handling the differences between 5.2.11 and 5.3, there shouldn't be any problem. When you recompile PHP, it should override your old version and replace it with the new one.

Comment: I've never compiled anything before, I'm not sure if it's safe to try. Aren't there other options?